# Javascript - getting a particular object from list based on property value

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I have a javascript   json result  list - self.data.allOrganizationsList

self.data.allOrganizationsList contains list of organization whose properties are

```
customentityaccess, id, isLabsAccessAllowed, memberCount, organizationname, organizationwebsite
```

i want to access an organization object which has 
id = 402881702121fec10121520080930001

I am trying to get this from the below statement, but since each item in the list is an object, i am unable to get the desired result.

```
self.data.allOrganizationsList.id['402881702121fec10121520080930001']`
//(or)
self.data.allOrganizationsList["id"]['402881702121fec10121520080930001']
```

Other alternative is to use the  $.each(self.data.allOrganizationList, function(index, item)).

But can i achieve the above result without iterating the - self.data.allOrganizationList

From the $.grept()

```
var myvar = $.grep(response.permissionedOrganizations, function(v) {
            return v.id === '40288170227c142201227eb56c5c000a';
        })[0];
console.log(myvar);
```

displays  undefined in console. Am i missing something.

Comment: By list you are referring to an *javascript array* of objects with those properties you've listed?

Comment: self.data.allOrganizationsList =  $.parseJSON(arraylist of java objects);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your structure, you want `$.grep` to filter out the correct element:

```
var arr = [
  {id: 1, value: 2},
  {id: 3, value: 4}
];

$.grep(arr, function(v) { return v.id === 3; })[0];  // second element
```

Note that this does iterating behind the scenes - there's not a way to get the correct element by using `[key]` notation as that's not how your structure is defined.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! in the statement [0] represents ?

Comment: @Sangram Anand: `$.grep` returns an array of all elements that match the function. In your case, that's always 1 since you're using an ID. So you get one-element arrays. To get the actual object, just get that (first) element.

Comment: getting undefined for the $.grep()  code. added code in the post.

Comment: @Sangram Anand: Are you using `self.data.allOrganizationsList` or `response.permissionedOrganizations`? What does the latter contain? Try `console.log(v)` inside the function and see what gets logged.

Comment: My bad.  i was using an another variable - response.permissionedOrganizations instead of self.data.allOrganizationsList.  Actually using $.each(response.permissionedOrganizations)  i get  id, and that id i need to search within  $.grep.  Its working now.  Thanks a ton..:)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery.grep( array, function(elementOfArray, indexInArray) [, invert] )

Finds the elements of an array which satisfy a filter function. The original array is not affected.
[check](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

Answer (score 0):

If it's an array, then it is not keyed by the id, so you need to loop over each item and check the id property, as you described above.

For you to be able to check by id it would have to be something like:

```
var allOrganizationsList =    
    {
        "id1": {
            "memberCount": 1
        },
        "id2": {
            "memberCount": 2
        }
    };

allOrganizationsList["id1"].memberCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to search more than one object based on the value, you can simply iterate the list once:

```
for (var i in list) {
    var id = list[i].id;
    my_table[id] = list[i];  // for unique ids
}
```

For non unique ids make `my_table` as an associative array of arrays:

```
if (!my_table[id]) my_table[id] = [list[i]];
else my_table[id].push(list[i]);
```

In the latter case my_table['12399123'] can return an array of results.